# Another instance of symfony2 for API

Tags: api, rest, symfony

I'm developing medium/large project and currently I will have to write API for it.

Project is currently on 2.2.11 because it don't need to be on the newest version and because of many installed modules it's hard to not crash something or module integrity can be broken.

I have found symfony rest edition https://github.com/gimler/symfony-rest-edition which looks pretty nice. The question is, installing another instance of symfony2 (with DB from my project) only for API is good practise? Or doing it in my current symfony instance is better option?

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad, many instances can be plugged to the same DB.

As you will share entities between those 2 instances, you should isolate them in a bundle that is embedded by the 2 instances, and versioned apart each instance. So that entities and repositories are shared and synchronized between the 2 projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [dependencies of the `symfony-rest-edition`](https://github.com/gimler/symfony-rest-edition/blob/2.3/composer.json) and try requiring them in your project. It's quite possible that you can get most of the components in one project, without having to duplicate code or adding deployment stages.

For example, the `master` branch of `FOSRestBundle` supports Symfony `~2.2`, see [`composer.json`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/composer.json#L26).

And globally, having duplicate code is not good. It's better to have everything in one project rather than dividing it. What if you'd have to change an entity or introduce new business logic? You'd have to make the change in two projects instead of one, or subdividing the codebase.